# How to Update the Information in Tkinter Window?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, position, tkinter, updates

(Python beginner, excuse me if the question is too childish) Below the label which says “Hello”, create a label or bar or whatever to show the updating positions of my two turtles (what I mean by updating is that as a turtle moves the two coordinates of its position changes at the same time)
    import Tkinter
    import turtle

```
def run_turtles(*args):
    for t, d in args:
        t.circle(250, d)
    root.after_idle(run_turtles, *args)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

frame = Tkinter.Frame(bg='black')
Tkinter.Label(frame, text=u'Hello', bg='grey', fg='white').pack(fill='x')
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(frame, width=750, height=750)
canvas.pack()
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

turtle1 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
turtle2 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

turtle1.ht(); turtle1.pu()
turtle1.left(90); turtle1.fd(250); turtle1.lt(90)
turtle1.st(); turtle1.pd()

turtle2.ht(); turtle2.pu()
turtle2.fd(250); turtle2.lt(90)
turtle2.st(); turtle2.pd()

root.deiconify()

run_turtles((turtle1, 3), (turtle2, 4))

root.mainloop()
```

Thank You Very Very Much!!

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the Label: `turtleLabel = Tkinter.Label(frame, text=u'Hello', bg='grey', fg='white')`

And then in your `run_turtles`-function you can update the label by setting its text:

```
turtleLabel['text'] = "Here be coordinates"
```

You can also change the text with the `configure` method:

```
turtleLabel.configure(text="Here be coordinates")
```

Note that you can't call `pack` in the same statement that you create the widget; `pack`returns `None` which would negate trying to save the reference to the widget.

Comment: turtleLabel["text"]=turtle1.pos() this is the code I add into ran_turtles but the program crashed on that line due to "NoneType" object does not support item assignment, so I'm a bit confused right now

Comment: @user2006082: the original version of this answer had a flaw that gives you the error you report. I've updated the answer to try and clarify.

Comment: Yes, my bad. As Bryan pointed out, move the call to .pack() to its own line below:
`turtleLabel = Tkinter.Label(frame, text=u'Hello', bg='grey', fg='white')
turtleLabel.pack(fill='x')`